# Proving a function to be convex under a specified condition

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am working on a problem and I encountered the given function. How can I prove a function:
$$ k(x) = \frac{1-e^{-\theta + \theta e^{-\lambda_1 x}}}{1-e^{-\theta + \theta e^{-\lambda_2 x}}}$$
is a concave function for $x>0$, $\theta>0$ and $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2$.
Its second derivative is very complicated. Though a sign plot for the second derivative confirms its convexity but I need to prove this mathematically.
Also
$$k''(x) = -\frac{\theta \lambda_1^2 e^{-\theta + \theta e^{-\lambda_1 x}-\lambda_1 x}(1+\theta e^{-\lambda_1 x})}{1-e^{-\theta + \theta e^{-\lambda_2 x}}}
    - \frac{2 \theta^2 \lambda_1 \lambda_2 e^{-2\theta + \theta( e^{-\lambda_1 x} + e^{-\lambda_2 x}) -(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)x }}{(1-e^{-\theta + \theta e^{-\lambda_2 x}})^2} \\
    + \frac{2\theta^2 \lambda_2^2 e^{-2\theta + 2\theta e^{-\lambda_2 x} - 2x\lambda_2} (1-e^{-\theta + \theta e^{-\lambda_1 x}})}{(1-e^{-\theta + \theta e^{-\lambda_2 x}})^3}
    + \frac{\theta \lambda_2^2 e^{-\theta + \theta e^{-\lambda_2 x} - x\lambda_2} (1-e^{-\theta + \theta e^{-\lambda_1 x}})(1+\theta e^{-\lambda_2 x})}{(1-e^{-\theta + \theta e^{-\lambda_2 x}})^2}$$
The main idea is to upper bound $k(x)$.

Comment: What's the derivative you calculated?

Comment: I calculated the second derivative over x and it's a long expression with four ratios.

Comment: Do you not also require $\theta > 0$?

Comment: Yes $\theta>0$.